# Axios response interceptor for refreshing token keeps firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**The logic:** On every request there's a JWT Authorization header that authenticates the user. If that expires, there's a cookie endpoint in place ready to refresh the JWT.

I am using **axios** and **interceptor response** to check if the client gets a **401** to try and refresh the JWT. The cookie may be valid or not.

The problem is that the interceptor to refresh the JWT never stops firing, and I think I have something wrong with the synchronization of the requests. Below is my code:

```
function refreshToken(dispatch) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance.put('/auth').then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_AUTH", payload: response.data });
      resolve(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

instance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      return response;
    },
    err => {
      const error = err.response;
      
      if (error.status === 401 && error.config && !error.config._retry) {
        error.config._retry = true;

        return refreshToken(dispatch).then((resp) => {
          return instance(error.config);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          return Promise.reject(e);
        });
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more then one parallel requests, refresh the JWT will be equal to the number of requests. Try to send `/auth` only first time and prevent next requests. You can use `localStorage` for this task.

```
let requests = [];

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response;
  },
  err => {
    const error = err.response;
    
    if (error.status === 401 && error.config && !error.config._retry) {
      requests.push(error.config);
      if (!localStorage.getItem('refresh')) {
        localStorage.setItem('refresh', 'done');
        error.config._retry = true;

        return refreshToken(dispatch).then((resp) => {
          localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
          
           const token = getAccessToken();
           requests.map(req => {
              req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
              return instance(req)
           })
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
          return Promise.reject(e);
        });
      }
    } else {
      requests = [];
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Checking for /auth is redundant and having the localStorage and _retry flag solves the firing problem. But now dispatch does not update the token fast enough for the return instance(error.config) to find the token. How can I address that?

Comment: It's no about `Dispatch does not update the token fast`, it work the same as before, but now it firing only one time and `instance(error.config);` will firing one time too. If you want to call all failed requests again, you must push them in array and then call `instance(error.config);` after `refreshToken` in array loop

Comment: Instead of pushing request configs to array you can do something like this `return sleepRequest(1000, instance(error.config);) ` https://gist.github.com/edmondburnett/38ed3451de659dc43fa3f24befc0073b

Comment: I can see 3 consecutive requests: 1st GET /auth 401 (checkAuth), 2nd PUT /auth 200 (refreshAuth), 3rd GET /auth 401 (checkAuth). On the 3rd one (which is the replay of the request), I print out the token and it's not there. In the localStorage I can see the token appearing and if I hit browser refresh, the user is logged in.

Comment: But for perfect it must be one request PUT /auth 200 (refreshAuth) and then request which failed with 401 status code

Comment: If I put the timeout as you suggested it works but it is odd that it needs something like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239396/discussion-between-vitaliy-rayets-and-mallix).